# Algorithm for Photoshop Bevel/Emboss layer style technique chisel soft

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I'm trying to recreate the layer style "bevel and emboss" with technique "chisel soft" in Javascript.

Here is a sample image and the filter applied.

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2Tc5.png)

[chisel soft, depth 100%, size 50px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP9wE.png)

The algorithms for techniques "smooth" and "chisel hard" are described in stackoverflow question https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/530/bitmap-alpha-bevel-algorithm. I believe the "chisel soft" technique is a variant that uses the same building blocks as chisel hard and smooth.

The official photoshop tells the following about the effects:
"Chisel Soft Uses a modified distance measurement technique and, although not as accurate as Chisel Hard, is more useful on a larger range of mattes. It preserves features better than the Smooth technique."

Technique: Chisel Hard

1. Compute HeightMap: Compute euclidean distance transform of the image. Pixels with alpha==1.0 are objects, pixels with alpha<1.0 are free space.
2. Comute Surface normals: The distance transform is interpreted as a height map. A surface normal can be determined computing dx/dy from neighboring vertical and horizontal values (e.g using simple difference operator or sobel filter.) These two numbers provide the normal required for the bump mapping
3. BumpMapping: The surface normals are combined with the global light source to compute the lighting intensity. The intensity is a value from -1 to 1 where negative values are shadows, positive values are highlights, and the absolute value is the magnitude of the light source.

Technique: Smooth

1. Compute HeightMap: Instead of computing the euclidean distance transform, for technique smooth the original image is smoothened using a two-pass box blur (approx. gaussian blur) of appropriate size.
2. Compute Surface normals: The result from 1. is interpreted as height map. The surface normals are computed like for chisel hard.
3. BumpMapping: see chisel hard.

Technique: Chisel Soft

I can only roughly tell what I have found out with some experiments.

1. Compute HeightMap:
   The height map seems to be a combination of two euclidean distance transforms and the alpha channel of the original image. The first distance transform treats pixels with alpha >= 0.5 as objects, others as free space.
   The second distance transform treats pixels with alpha <= 0.5 as objects, others as free space.
   Unfortunately I don't have any idea how to combine these parts to get the correct effect.
   Steps 2 and 3 are probably identical to technique "smooth" and "chisel hard".

Any ideas are highly appreciated!